# Editing a BIG XML via DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, memory

If there is a very big XML and DOM parser is used to parse it.
Now there is a requirement to add/delete elements from the XML i.e edit the XML
How to edit the XML as the entire XML will not be loaded due to memory constraints ?
What could be the strategy to solve this ?

Comment: The requirement is that SAX parser is not to be used

Comment: Why is this a requirement? Can you use a StAX parser?

Answer (score 2):

You may consider to use a SAX parser instead, which doesn't keep the whole document in memory. It will be faster and will also use much less memory.

Answer (score 2):

As two other answers mentioned already, a SAX parser will do the trick. Your other alternative to DOM is a [StAX parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX).

> Traditionally, XML APIs are either:
>
> - DOM based - the entire document is read into memory as a tree
>     structure for random access by the calling application
> - event based - the application registers to receive events as
>     entities are encountered within the source document.
>
> Both have advantages; the former (for example, DOM) allows for random
>   access to the document, the latter (e.g. SAX) requires a small memory
>   footprint and is typically much faster.
>
> These two access metaphors can be thought of as polar opposites. A
>   tree based API allows unlimited, random access and manipulation, while
>   an event based API is a 'one shot' pass through the source document.
>
> StAX was designed as a median between these two opposites. In the StAX
>   metaphor, the programmatic entry point is a cursor that represents a
>   point within the document. The application moves the cursor forward -
>   'pulling' the information from the parser as it needs. This is
>   different from an event based API - such as SAX - which 'pushes' data
>   to the application - requiring the application to maintain state
>   between events as necessary to keep track of location within the
>   document.

Answer (score 1):

StAX is my preferred approach for handling large documents.  If DOM is a requirement, check out DOM implementations like Xerces that support lazy construction of DOM nodes:

- http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/faq-write.html#faq-4

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption of memory constraint loading the XML document may only apply to DOM. VTD-XML loads the entire XML in memory, and does it efficiently (1.3x the size of XML document)... both in memory and performance...

http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf

Another distinct benefit, which none other XML framework in existence has, is its incremental update capability...

http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/36379

Answer (score -1):

As stivlo mentioned you can use a SAX parser for reading the XML.

But for writing the XML you can write into fileoutput stream as plain text. I am sure that you will get requirement that mentions after which tag or under which tag the new data should be inserted.

Comment: @MattBall Great man, you give -1 for giving ideas that worked for me. And more over i didn't know people where putting marks for the answers posted here. If you do this, i suppose people will not come with constructive ideas.